# In Python Sphinx, is there a way to hide autodoc setup code?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, doctest, autodoc

I am using Sphinx autodoc to document my Python code.  Examples in my documentation contain:

- Uninteresting set up code I do not want rendered in the HTML documentation
- Code that should appear in the documentation

For example:

```
Then you process file `example.txt` with `frobnicate()`:

    >>> with open('example.txt', 'w') as f:
    ...     _ = f.write("first boring line\\n")
    ...     _ = f.write("second boring line\\n")

    >>> frobnicate('example.txt')
    True
```

I want Sphinx autodoc to hide the uninteresting set up code so that the rendered HTML output from Sphinx contains only:

```
Then you process file example.txt with frobnicate():

    >>> frobnicate('example.txt')
    True
```

Obviously I still want doctest to execute the entire example as usual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the uninteresting setup code in a [`testsetup`](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/doctest.html#directive-testsetup) block.

```
.. testsetup:: *

   with open('example.txt', 'w') as f:
       _ = f.write("first boring line\\n")
       _ = f.write("second boring line\\n")

Then you process file `example.txt` with `frobnicate()`:

>>> frobnicate('example.txt')
True
```

Comment: I had to use `>>>` at the start of setup lines (but with setup lines still intended) for this to work